# Nil out NSFetchedResultsController Delegate when offscreen?

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Is it best practice to Nil out NSFetchedResultsController Delegate when offscreen?

For example, I have a list managed by a NSFRC. When I tap a list item, I get a detail view. I can potentially change something on a detail view that will remove it from the list. Or, if I continue to slide through the detail views, I can cause it to load in more data (which would subsequently update the parent table view NSFRC).

I'm getting strange behavior when I DO nil it out. Can't seem to find advice on this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to nil out your NSFRC here. In fact, this is the main convenience of having your tableView managed by an NSFRC, is that it will update itself appropriately while you are off in other views changing data. This also applies data changes sequentially, rather than having to refetch all data when returning to your list.

Comment: From what I understand, the main convenience of NSFRC is for data changes that happen in the background for whatever reason (fetching new data), not when you are offscreen on another view. Otherwise it wouldn't be inserting things with animations, etc.

Comment: if you breakpoint your NSFRC delegate methods, you will see them getting called when you are manipulating relevant data in other views, as long as it is in memory. The FRC doesn't know anything about your tableView or it's animations. Your tableview will decide whether to animate an insertion if that row is visible. Either way, when you return to your list, the new rows are already there if your FRC was receiving updates while your list was offscreen.

Comment: I know it fires when in the background, just wasn't sure if this was a good practice or not. I just meant that typically you use it to insert rows into your tables with animations, etc.

Comment: It is a good practice. Even though the animation won't occur, your tableView delegate will alloc init or dequeue a cell for your new row upon data insertion, one by one. This prevents needing to do a full reload of your tableView upon return which is less performant.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a similar question time ago, looking for a technical explanation of this 'best practice'. However I didn't find anything.

I suppose that much of the suggested 'best practices' came from older iOS version, where `viewDidUnload` could have been called in case of memory warning, but that's not the case anymore.

In my experience, I found out that it is only mandatory to resign in case of background update and merge. All the other case depends on your application logic.

For example when you have nested CoreData entities with subsequent UIView, like so:

```
child1 (UITableView)-->child2 (Detail)-->child3 --> (UITableView)-->ecc...
```

Then, a change on child3 will have the child 1 table view react on that change, so you may want to avoid unnecessary call to a remote fetched controller, by resigning as delegate or introspecting the changement and returning YES or NO within the delegate method. It could be simpler and much efficient to refetch the query.

Keeping the same structure, suppose you have a mass update on latest UITableView by merging two context, if you have used the same context for all the controllers, then they will be trying to update its view even if not needed.

So for a simple case like UITableView-->UIView (detail) I can see no problem of keeping delegate assigned, all the other case, I would do a little analysis.